# Are && statements and nested conditionals of the following code equivalent?

Tags: java, boolean, conditional-statements

If x and y are int variables. Are the following two segments of Java code behaviourally equivalent for all values of x and y?  Explain why, or why not.

Version 1:

```
if (x > 10)
  {
  if (y < 20)
  {System.out.print("hi");
  }
}
```

Version 2:

```
if (x > 10 && y < 20)
{
System.out.print("hi");
}
```

I think it is equivalent but I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything. I don't see how they cannot be equivalent. Thanks.

Comment: here, the result will be the same indeed.

Comment: yes but if there are lot of nested ifs then 1st is nice

Comment: `&&` is not a *statement*, it's an *operator*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are completely equivalent. In situations like these it comes down to picking the one you think is clearest.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are.

The important point which might not be so obvious is that in both versions the second comparison is only evaluated if the first one results in 'true'.

Comment: Nice point on short circuits. A lot of people will likely miss that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are equivalent, but the second one is shorter, and you can add a single `else` clause, which you cannot do in the first, because you'd have to write two independent `else` clauses there.

Whether one or two `else` clauses should be used depends on what your logic requires, so both forms may be appropriate.

I would *generally* recommend the second one, but if you don't need a single `else` clause, and the expressions are large, the first one may end up being more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are equivalent also from the semantic point of view.